# SqlSessionTemplate is not serializable in flink

Tags: serialization, apache-flink, mybatis, flink-streaming

My flink aplication throws such exception when it starts:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy@3fe8ad3f is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:171)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:146)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:146)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:146)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:91)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.clean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1606)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.clean(DataStream.java:178)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.addSink(DataStream.java:1240)
    at com.pdd.service.koduck.realtime.flink.operators.baseLayer.PlanProcessor.afterProcess(PlanProcessor.java:90)
    at com.pdd.service.koduck.realtime.flink.operators.baseLayer.Processor.process(Processor.java:43)
    at com.pdd.service.koduck.realtime.flink.Runner.run(Runner.java:49)
    at com.pdd.service.koduck.realtime.flink.Main.main(Main.java:27)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:576)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:153)
    ... 11 more
```

I think the reason is that one of my SinkFunction reference a Mybatis Mapper object which reference a non-serializable SqlSessionTemplate.
This is my sink Function:

```
    public class MySinkFunction2<T> extends RichSinkFunction<List<PlanDailyTable.Row>> {
        private PlanDailyDtoMapper mapper;

        public MySinkFunction2(PlanDailyDtoMapper mapper) {
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }

        @Override
        public void invoke(List<PlanDailyTable.Row> value, Context context) throws Exception {
            mapper.insertMultiRow(value);
        }
    }
```

How to solve this problem? Need some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than instantiating the Mapper object in the constructor, you can do this in the sink's `open` method, and then make the Mapper `transient`.

The sink's constructor is called on the Flink client, and the sink has to be serialized and sent to the task managers. Whereas the sink's open method is called once in each task manager as the job begins.